# Python for loop glitching out

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, for-loop, pycharm

My program starts off like this

```
array=[[[0,0]]*4]*4
for i in range(4):
    for k in range(4):
        array[i][k]=[i,k]

for n in range(4):
    print(array[n])
```

but outputs this

````
[[3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]
[[3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]
[[3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]```

I'm using 3.11, I tried switching i and k around, switching the names for the variables, doing
````

array[i][k][0]=k
array[i][k][1]=i

````
etc. but none of it has worked. I want it to output 
```[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3]]
[[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3]]
[[2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3]]
[[3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [[[0, 0]] * 4] * 4
```

You think you have many independent lists of zero-pairs.

But really there's just a small number of lists
with a bunch of pointers to them.
That is, each assignment updates a single list element,
but because multiple outer lists point at the container,
the update appears to affect multiple locations.

---

You would be happier with
[pip install numpy](https://pypi.org/project/numpy)
(`import numpy as np`) and assigning

```
array = np.array([[[0, 0]] * 4] * 4)
```

That will allocate separate integer storage
for each cell, and you can update them
independently to your heart's content,
without surprises.

---

Here is a simpler demonstration of the effect
you were seeing.

```
>>> a = b = c = [5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> a
[5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> b
[5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> c
[5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> a[2] = 20
>>> 
>>> a
[5, 6, 20, 8]
>>> 
>>> b
[5, 6, 20, 8]
>>> 
>>> c
[5, 6, 20, 8]
```

Notice that `b` is a pointer to the *same* list as `a`,
and likewise `c`.

There's just one list, and it doesn't
have a single name. In a sense any of those
three names is equally valid. We have three
references to the identical underlying list.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be thought as the cartesian product of two arrays `[0, 1, 2, 3]`. You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to achieve this pretty easily.

```
import itertools 

list(itertools.product([0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]))
```

Returns

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), 
 (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), 
 (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), 
 (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

It's also the equivalent of just doing:

```py
[[x, y] for x in [0, 1, 2, 3] for y in [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], 
 [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], 
 [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], 
 [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]
```